# How to create custom admin pages in 4.x?

Tags: keystonejs

I need to add a custom admin page to the back office (/keystone). It will not be model related, but some custom UI for additional nodejs calls. What is the best way to achieve that (without hijacking the keystone admin code in /node_modules)?

Any help/hint appreciated.

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: Keystone doesn't have any extensibility for its own Admin UI, unfortunately. You'll need to create an entirely separate route to get the functions you want; it can't be hosted within Keystone's Admin UI.